# Windows phone 8.1 store passwords and files locally

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to store passwords for windows phone 8.1 application written in c# but I do not know the best way to do this. I want these files to be encrypted and I prefer to serialize objects directly into the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the password, via [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string) and I would store them in a binary file via [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use a binary reader [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the passwords back. Of course you would need to encrypt the password the user entered to see if it matches the saved password.

Also, what do you have so far?